# VSCode settings.json data structures explanation

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

Consider this block of code in my `settings.json` VScode config:

```
{
...
    "python.linting.pep8Args": [
        "--ignore=E501",
        "--ignore=E401",
        "--ignore=E402",
    ],
    "[python]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
...
}
```

How do the `python.<foo>` and `"[python]": ...` statements relate?

Trying to make sense of the data structures; does `"[python]":...` just make a shorthand for defining `python.editor.tabSize`, etc. for all elements within braces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "python" settings are specific to the Python extension for VS Code. The "[python]" subgroup are settings you specified that are specific to the Python *language*. Basically the latter is a mechanism for editor settings which vary per language (e.g. using tabs in Go but spaces in Python).